# Solve the product of these permutations.

Tags: permutations

This is just a simple product of permutations, can someone check my math?
$$
(1234)(15792)(1932)(348)= (134)(2579)(8)
$$
Yes? Where did I go wrong if it's incorrect?

Here was my order of thinking(left to right):[1 to 9, 9 to 2, 2 to 3.  Then 3 to 4, 4 to 1, close][2 to 1, 1 to 5. 5 to 7. 7 to 9, 9 to 3 so close][then 8 is left by itself].

Comment: There are actually several ways that people read and write permutations: whether they're treated as left or right actions and what way to read the order within the permutation.  It would be helpful if you could explain your calculation so that others know what conventions you are using.

Comment: Consider what happens to $1$. On the RHS it is mapped to $3$. Where does it go on the LHS?

Answer (score 1):

Yes , it is correct.

If we have $ \{1 ,2 ,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\} $ after both permutations we will get $ \{3, 5, 1, 8, 7, 6, 9, 2, 4\} $

You can check this by the following [cpp code](https://ideone.com/1iwhmc)